# Django def __str__ list index out of range

Tags: python, django, string

Working through the Django tutorial.

Python 3.4
Django 1.7

"Wait a minute.  is, utterly, an unhelpful representation of this object. Let’s fix that by editing the Question model (in the polls/models.py file) and adding a **str**() method to both Question and Choice:"

```
>>> from django.db import models
>>> class Question(models.Model):
...     def __str__(self):
...             return self.question_text
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 117, in __new__
kwargs = {"app_label": package_components[app_label_index]}
IndexError: list index out of range
```

And then I receive the same error when I try and edit class Choice(models.Model) as well.  I hope this gives you enough information.  Let me know what other information I should include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Django expects models [to be created in specific places](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/#creating-models), typically the `models.py` file. This will allow [the `app_label` meta field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/#app-label), among other things, to be automatically generated.

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        app_label = "something"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

Since you are creating the model within the interpreter, you need to set the `app_label` meta field on your own, so Django doesn't have to guess where it is supposed to be. You may also want to consider setting up the models outside of the interpreter, as they are meant to be within concrete modules and refer to existing tables.

If you are trying to generate a model for an existing table, you should also set up [the `db_table` meta field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/#table-names). Django will automatically generate a table name, and it most likely won't match the existing name.

Answer (score 0):

Your excepton is thrown in [`/django/db/models/base.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py) and i thin

By looking at the code i guess that setting `app_label = 'yourappname'` in your Meta would solve your issue.